# PHP SOAP/CURL Request returns error

Tags: php, web-services, datetime, curl, soap

**Situation:** I am having to submit SOAP data to a remote server. The first request is for a URL that is needed for the second request. The URL returned starts the second request and is supposed to give me a return response of a bunch of user data in XML format.

**Problem:** I am getting an error back from the server on the second request (the data) that is referring to a C# problem and I do not know how to get around this. The error that I am trying to troubleshoot is:

> The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime
>   did not have the Kind property set correctly

HERE IS MY CODING

**PHP:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $soapUrl = "https://domain.com/insidews/insidews.asmx";
    $soapUser = "*******";
    $soapPassword = "***************************";

    // xml post structure

    $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                          <soap:Header>
                            <inCredentials xmlns="http://inlogin.com/inSideWS">
                              <busNo>****************</busNo>
                              <password>******************</password>
                            </inCredentials>
                          </soap:Header>
                          <soap:Body>
                            <GetURL xmlns="http://inlogin.com/inSideWS" />
                          </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>';

       $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "SOAPAction: http://inlogin.com/inSideWS/GetURL", 
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

        $url = $soapUrl;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }               
        curl_close($ch);
        //echo $response;
        // converting
        $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);
        $parser = new SimpleXmlElement($response2);

        foreach($parser as $p)  {
            foreach($p as $n)   {
                $new_url = $n;
            }
        }

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dateone = '12/1/2013 00:00:00';
$startdate = new DateTime($dateone,$timezone);
$startdate = $startdate->format('c');

echo "Start Date: ".$startdate."<br><br>";

$datetwo = '12/31/2013 23:59:59';
$enddate = new DateTime($datetwo,$timezone);
$enddate = $enddate->format('c');

echo "End Date: ".$enddate."<br><br>";

echo "<font style='font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;'>FILE GET Destination URL:</font> ".$new_url."<br><br>";
$xml_post_string_2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                      <soap:Header>
                        <inCredentials xmlns="http://inlogin.com/inSideWS">
                          <busNo>**************</busNo>
                          <password>*******************************</password>
                          <timeZoneName>UTC</timeZoneName>
                        </inCredentials>
                      </soap:Header>
                      <soap:Body>
                        <DataDownloadReport_Run xmlns="http://inlogin.com/inSideWS">
                          <reportNo>16</reportNo>
                          <startDate>'.$startdate.'</startDate>
                          <endDate>'.$enddate.'</endDate>
                        </DataDownloadReport_Run>
                      </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>';

$new_headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "SOAPAction: http://inlogin.com/inSideWS/DataDownloadReport_Run", 
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string_2),
                ); 


// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$cho = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string_2); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($cho, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $new_headers);

// converting

$second_response = curl_exec($cho); 
//  var_dump($second_response);
//  var_dump(curl_getinfo($cho));
 // var_dump(curl_error($cho));
if(curl_errno($cho)){
    echo '<br><br>Curl error: ' . curl_error($cho);
}   

//echo $second_response;
print_r($second_response);
curl_close($cho);

// converting
$new_response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$second_response);
$new_response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$new_response1);

// convertingc to XML
$new_parser = simplexml_load_string($second_response);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Start Date: 2013-12-01T00:00:00+00:00

End Date: 2013-12-31T23:59:59+00:00

FILE GET Destination URL: https://domain.com/inSideWS/inSideWS.asmx

 string(0) "" soap:ServerSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentException: The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly. For example, when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local. Parameter name: sourceTimeZone at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone, TimeZoneInfoOptions flags) at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) at UCN.Common.TimeZoneUtilities.ConvertUTCToTimeZone(DateTime time, String id) in d:\Agents\7\inContact\RC-Web.inSideWS\Sources\C#\Library\Common\Utilities\TimeZoneUtilities.cs:line 109 at inContact.DataDownload.Report.GetData(String dataSourceModule, Int32 reportType) in d:\Agents\7\inContact\RC-Web.inSideWS\Sources\C#\Library\inContact.DataDownload\Report.cs:line 128 at inContact.DataDownload.Report.RunReport(Nullable`1 busNo, Nullable`1 reportNo, Nullable`1 maximumRows, Nullable`1 startIndex, String orderColumn, Nullable`1 orderASC, String searchText, Nullable`1& rowCount) in d:\Agents\7\inContact\RC-Web.inSideWS\Sources\C#\Library\inContact.DataDownload\Report.cs:line 78 at inSideWebService.inSideWS.DataDownloadReport_Run(Int32 reportNo, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the call using PHPs soap library, it takes care of most of the headers and intricacies associated with SOAP. The documentation is here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php.

Comment: WOW NEVER THOUGHT ABOUT THAT (sarcasm doesn't do well in text form)! Seriously though I looked at all my options, and using CURL to pass my SOAP was the best way of doing what I need to for my needs. And by the way, the link you offered is not a valid link, you just pasted a nonsense link I pasted in my code.

Comment: Actually you might go and take a look at this: http://www.halon.se/blog/making-phps-soap-client-asynchronous/. Inside you will find a script that uses SoapClient to create request, and allows cURL to take over when the request is actually made. While the solution uses globals and is not-so-good, it does show how cURL can be used and Soap specifics simplified.
https://github.com/halonsecurity/sp-enduser/commit/4ef77895bd334bf04a1d90f035a317c4dd3838ef

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. Translating the DateTime from PHP to C# should have worked but for some reason C# was not accepting the ISO8601 format like it was supposed to (as I was told it did). So I simply changed the following coding for the date:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$time = time("00:00:00");
$dateone = '12/1/2013 00:00:00';
$startdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateone)) . 'T' . date("H:i:s", strtotime($dateone));

$datetwo = '12/31/2013 23:59:59';
$enddate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetwo)) . 'T' . date("H:i:s", strtotime($datetwo));
```

This fixed the problem and I am now getting a response from the server.